# Method overloading - Warning message in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, overloading

I've two methods as shown below:

First method:

```
public int function(int i) {
    //some calculation
    return i;
}
```

Second method:

```
private String function(String s) {
    //some calculation
    return s;
}
```

Both the methods are never used anywhere (since the coding is not yet completed). But for the second method, I'm getting the following warning in eclipse:

```
The method function(String) from the type Test is never used locally
```

Why this warning is not displaying for first method also?

Comment: Because you didn't call that method in any part of your code and it's being "private", eclipse is warning you to use it in local class or do something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method is `private`, so if you don't call it inside your class you will get the warning message *The method function(String) from the type Test is never used locally*

But the first method is `public` and eclipse doesn't know if it is called in your project or by other projects thats why you don't have the same warning message.

Answer (score 4):

Warning is not displayed for first one, because it is `public` and you could use it for example in external libraries. The second one is `private` so that means it could be used only in class containing it and if it's unused you will get a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Because the first method is public, eclipse has no way of knowing if it is used or not, while with the private method it can see that the method is not used anywhere in that class.

Comment: Of course it does! It is just not being used in the current project.

Comment: And how would eclipse know that it's not part of an API exposed to another project?

Comment: This answer is correct. Shame on the downvoter. NB Eclipse doesn't even warn for package-private method, for similar reasons.

Comment: @Marko I see that we are at cross purposes. Eclipse can and does determine what API parts are used in the current project. As ivani says, it cannot know how it is used outside of the project. The answer omitted that aspect, and that was the point I (poorly) tried to make. I think we are in total agreement about the facts :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because if you set a method as `private` Eclipse assume you are going to use it inside some other public method.

While `public` methods are always accessible, private are invokable only inside the class they are declared.

So a `private` unused method is actually an useless peace of code...